# Tomcat doesn't respond, threadump shows a blocked thread

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it bad if I see the following in a Tomcat thread dump? The server is sometimes getting "stuck" and not responding to http requests and I'm wondering if this blocked thread is an indication that it has some kind of network connectivity problem.

```
http-80-10" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000015ac5000 nid=0x2dc in Object.wait() [0x000000001d4af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005805380a0> (a java.util.HashMap)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.net.InetAddress.checkLookupTable(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please spend a few minutes reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for what questions are appropriate for this site. A general rule is that if it's not a question directly related to writing your own application or library, or using a programming related tool or library, it's not on-topic here. Voting to move to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) where it's more appropriate. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ken - Tomcat is an application server...judging by the question above it looks like there's threading problem in the application **code** running in Tomcat to I'm happy for it to remain here. Now if this was a configuration problem or a problem with Tomcat not starting then I could see the reason to migrate.

Comment: @Kev, with all due respect: I'm familiar with what Tomcat is; however, there's no code posted that would make the question answerable AFAICT. "Is it bad I see 'Thread.State: BLOCKED'?" can be answered "Yes" or "No" only. I guess I could have voted to close it as "not a real question" or "subjective", as the question of whether it's bad or not would be a matter of opinion (mostly that it is bad, I think). :) There's no code to assist with, no information to use that would help solve an undescribed problem other than a line in a thread dump. How would you answer it as asked?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like this bug:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7012768

My first thought was that it was it was contending and doing a lot of very slow DNS lookups, but the above bug would seem far more likely.